# How to search an array for an int value that has already been entered previously

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm making a simple guessing game program. The user enters a value out of 100 and the program tells the user if their guess is too high or low. I want to make it so the program lets the user know that they've already entered that current number in previously. How would I implement a loop into my program that would take the users guess and compare it to the array list to look for duplicate values?

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
#include <cstdlib>

int main() 
{
  srand(time(0));
  const int SIZE = 100; //array
  int number[SIZE];
  int i;
  int numb = rand() % 100; //rng
  cout <<"Hint: "<< numb << endl;
  cout << " " << endl;
  cout << "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. Guess what it is: ";
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    cin >> number[i];
      if (number[i] == numb)  
      {
        cout << "Correct! It's " << numb << endl; //if user guesses correct
        break;
      }
      else if (number[i] < numb) //if user guesses too low
      {
        cout << "That's too low! guess again: " ;
      }
      else if (number[i] > numb) //if user guesses too high
      {
        cout <<  "That's too high! guess again: " ;
      }           
  }
}
```

Comment: keep all previously entered values in a std::set and check if it was previously entered when you get a new one

Comment: Don't straightaway add the number to the array. Hold it in a temporary variable, iterate over the number array to check for duplicates, and add only if no duplicate was found. Do not accept values that are out of accepted range in your number array. In this case, < 1 and >100. Do it this way only if you are not supposed to use STL.

Answer (score 0):

Create a vector for already typed values:

```
vector <int> atyped;
```

Create a function to check and return true or false:

```
int check(int entered_value, vector <int> atyped) {
ret=0;
  for (int i=0;i<atyped.size();i++){
    if (enterd_value==atyped[i])
     ret=1;
  }
return ret;
}
```

Then all you have to do is:

```
if (check(number[i])!=0)
cout << "Sorry, you already tried that one!" <<endl;
```

Hope this can at least give you an idea as to how to solve your problem ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Only problem I have is that I haven't learned about vectors yet in my class. Do you know a way I could do this with just loops and arrays? Thanks

Comment: std::find can be used to check for the element. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Comment: @Paul9o7 Create large enough array (you will have to limit the user entries here, you will probably have no more than 101 entries if both 0 and 100 are accepted) and count entries. Then you can traverse the array to the number of entries (because of 0 index) and check if the number already exists.  You can also play with search algorithms if you already studied that in school.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  cin >> number[i];
  if  (number[i] == numb)
  {
    cout << "Correct! It's " << numb << endl; //if user guesses correct
    break;
  }
  else if (std::find(number, number + i, number[i]) != number + i) 
  {
    cout <<  "You already guessed that! guess again: " ;
  }
  else if  ... // existing higher or lower
}
```

The range of pointers `[number, number + i)` is all the previous guesses. `find` returns the first matching pointer, or the end (`number + i`) if there is no match.